# String(format:) Crashes in iOS 7 - Need an alternative. THREAD 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)

Tags: ios, string, swift

The String(format:) method is crashing my app in iOS 7 but it works fine in iOS 8. Is there anything I can use to get the same effect here that works in both?

The error message I'm getting is: `THREAD 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)` with just `(lldb)` in the console.

I'm getting this error on an all 7.1 simulator devices and an iPhone 4 7.1.2 device.

```
func configureLoadingIcon() {
    loadingImage.alpha = 0.0
    loadingImage.animationImages = [UIImage]()
    for var index = 0; index < 48; index++ {

        // Need an alternative to this line
        var frameName = String(format: "loading_%05d", index)

        loadingImage.animationImages?.append(UIImage(named: frameName)!)
    }
    loadingImage.animationDuration = 1.3
    loadingImage.startAnimating()
}
```

//Edit

I'm now doing this... but still no joy on iOS 7...

```
func configureLoadingIcon() {
    loadingImage.alpha = 0.0
    loadingImage.animationImages = [UIImage]()
    var frameName: String
    for var i = 0; i < 48; i++ {
        let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 2
        let formattedIndex = formatter.stringFromNumber(i)
        var frameName = String(format: "loading_000%@", formattedIndex!)
        loadingImage.animationImages?.append(UIImage(named: frameName)!)
    }
    loadingImage.animationDuration = 1.3
    loadingImage.startAnimating()
}
```

I also tried `var frameName = "loading_000\(formattedIndex)"` but that didn't seem to work.. not sure why.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `String(format: ...)` is the culprit? Try to remove all other code, in particular `UIImage(named: frameName)!` – Does it still crash? Does it crash in the Simulator or on the device? Which devices?

Comment: (Of course you could use NSNumberFormatter instead, but I don't yet see why your code should crash at that point.)

Comment: Any iOS 7.1 simulator. I've tried commenting out everything except the for loop and it still crashes.

Comment: Strange, I cannot reproduce that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var frameName = "loading_000\(formattedIndex!)"` was the only alternative that worked.

```
func configureLoadingIcon() {
    loadingImage.alpha = 0.0
    loadingImage.animationImages = [UIImage]()
    var frameName: String
    for var i = 0; i < 48; i++ {
        let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 2
        let formattedIndex = formatter.stringFromNumber(i)
        var frameName = "loading_000\(formattedIndex!)"
        loadingImage.animationImages?.append(UIImage(named: frameName)!)
    }
    loadingImage.animationDuration = 1.3
    loadingImage.startAnimating()
}
```

Comment: I have been struggling with exact same scenario using `String(format)` to build a soap message for a web service. I also changed it to what you have using `\()` and its working now. This has to be some Swift bug I imagine. My example was a bit more complex than what you have here but only in the sense that I had like 10 values I was adding to string. Crazy.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your code works different between 32 and 64 bit. %05d is a format for C / C++ / Objective-C 'int'. index probably has type Int which is either 32 or 64 bit. %05zd should work fine.

%05d might pick the wrong 32 bits of a 64 bit Int, produce a name with a random large integer, UIImage (named:...) returns nil, and you get a crash.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but I tried the code both in iPhone 5 (32-bit) and iPhone 5s (64-bit) simulator, and "%05d" worked both times correctly. Strange ...

Comment: I'm going to try and get hold of an iOS 7.1 device and see if it's just a simulator issue. Adding zd didn't help.